# How to keep the default column header popup menu on devexpress?

Tags: c#, devexpress

I have added a right click popup menu on my grid content. This popup also shows when I right click the grid header, however, I want to keep the default column header popup menu.

My right menu code is like this:

```
protected override void RightClickMenu()
{
    this.rightClickContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    this.rightClickContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("MY CLASSES", new System.EventHandler(myclasses_Click));
    this.rightClickContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("MY BOOK LISTS", new System.EventHandler(booklists_Click));

    this.gridView.PopupMenuShowing += gridView_PopupMenuShowing;
}
```

Does anyone have any idea what I should add in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`GridView.CalcHitInfo`](https://documentation.devexpress.com/#WindowsForms/DevExpressXtraGridViewsGridGridView_CalcHitInfotopic1368) method to determine where the right mouse button was clicked. And if it was clicked on column header then you must set your `GridControl.ContextMenu` property to `null`.
Here is example:

```
protected override void RightClickMenu()
{
    this.rightClickContextMenu = new ContextMenu();

    this.rightClickContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("MY CLASSES", new System.EventHandler(myclasses_Click));
    this.rightClickContextMenu.MenuItems.Add("MY BOOK LISTS", new System.EventHandler(booklists_Click));

    this.gridView.PopupMenuShowing += gridView_PopupMenuShowing;
    this.gridView.MouseDown += gridView_MouseDown;
}

private void gridView_MouseDown(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Button != MouseButtons.Right)
        return;

    var hitInfo = this.gridView.CalcHitInfo(e.Location);

    if (!hitInfo.InColumn)
        this.gridView.GridControl.ContextMenu = this.rightClickContextMenu;
    else
        this.gridView.GridControl.ContextMenu = null;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It is quite hard to suggest something without understanding all the aspects of this situation. You should [report this issue](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Create) directly to DevExpress Support team and provide a sample project where the issue is reproducible. I believe their guys can diagnose the error using your sample and fix it or point you into the right direction with ContextMenu usage on GridControl.

Related support-article: [Both ContextMenu and grid menu are shown simultaneously](https://www.devexpress.com/Support/Center/Question/Details/T115021)